# Hi, all I just wanted to see if anyone knows the formula for a quintic bezier curve

Tags: curves

If possible I'd like to find out the formula for a quintic bezier curve. I have a set of 6 static points that I need to turn into a parametric equation and would like to be able to do it a simpler way than going through each individual step

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, the wikipedia page given by @ad2004 is great. I used the "Explicit Definition" section to write a bezier function that's working exactly as intended. But secondly, for what I'm inferring from your question are your purposes... you realize that $B(t), 0\leq t\leq 1$ will only go through your first and last control points, right? That is, $B(0), B(1)$ will evaluate to your first and last control points, respectively. But there's typically no $t$ for which $B(t)$ exactly passes through any other control point (unless they all happen to lie on a straight line, or other special case).

Comment: Yes indeed, The page is great and is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be what you are looking for.  For $n=5$

\begin{align}
\mathbf{B}(t) &= (1 - t)^5\mathbf{P}_0 + 5t(1 - t)^4\mathbf{P}_1 + 10t^2(1 - t)^3 \mathbf{P}_2 + 10t^3 (1-t)^2 \mathbf{P}_3 + 5t^4(1-t) \mathbf{P}_4 + t^5 \mathbf{P}_5 && 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1
\end{align}

It was an example from the Bezier wiki:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve in the section named "Explicit definition".

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is extremely helpful